# executemany() performing very slow

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python + mysql to insert a large amount of data into a db (about 120k rows).

On the development server (wampp), my pyhton script takes about 16 seconds to insert everything, but when I try to use my Amazon EC2, connecting directly to the 'localhost' a local user, it takes about 5 minutes to execute the same process.

I have a procedure in PHP, where the query is an `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`

```
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USERNAME = 'admin'
DB_PASSWORD = ''
DB_NAME = 'db_name'

def connect_to_database() ->  PooledMySQLConnection | MySQLConnection | CMySQLConnection | None:
    return mysql.connector.connect(host=DB_HOST,user=DB_USERNAME,password=DB_PASSWORD,database=DB_NAME)

def job():
    console.log('Updating data..')
    clean_db()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as schedule_executor:
        schedule_executor.map(threading, symbols)
    update_db()
    console.log('Job finished :)')

def threading():
    data1 = [(), ()..] # here i have 300 tuples in the list
    stmt = f"CALL my_procedure(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    console.log('Connecting to DB..')
    conn = connect_to_database()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(stmt, data1)
    console.log('Commit..')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Do you have to use a procedure for the insert? If you call `executemany()` on an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` query, it will batch them up and this usually makes it much faster.

Comment: The `f` on your `stmt` declaration is not only unnecessary, it's one step away from a SQL injection bug.

Comment: @Barmar i changed everything according your tip... but still "slow"... i need it fo finish under 30seconds... any other way to improve this?

Comment: Are they both using SSD drives?